# Изменить цвет ячейки при клике

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как менять цвет ячейки при клике

```
<td @click="changeSelect($event)"
   v-for="(n, index) in 10">{{ n }}
</td>
```

В методе меняю цвет ячейки, но при клике на другую красный цвет у прошлой остаётся, а нужно чтоб при клике только одна была подкрашена красным

```
changeSelect(event){
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
},
```

Comment: сбросьте цвет всех ячеек, а потом устанавливайте красный кликнутой

Comment: Не могу, это часть кода для примера, там изначально еще в определенных ячейках установлены цвета

Comment: используйте css класс, который вы установите для кликнутой ячейки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используете `vue`, можно на каждую ячейку "повесить" `key` и его использовать для того, чтобы ячейке, на которой "кликнули", присвоить дополнительный класс `css`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activeIndex: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    changeSelect(index) {
      this.activeIndex = index
    },
  },
})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

td:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="i in 4">
      <td v-for="j in 9"
        :key="`${i}${j}`"
        :class="{active: `${i}${j}` == activeIndex, green: i === 2 && j ===2}"
        @click="changeSelect(`${i}${j}`)"
       >
        {{ i }}{{ j }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```