# Item click меняющий фон блока

Tags: vue.js

Как реализовать 10 блоков который будут активны
На активный блок менять его фон
Если нажали на другой блок старый станет в прежный background, а активный поменяет свой цвет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190092/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5/1190355#1190355

Comment: немного задача изменилась у меня, нужно + сделать toggle click на каждый блок, старая задача получилась ....

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `key` для того, чтобы отметить `div`, на котором "кликнули", дополнительным классом `css`, перед присвоением класса - проверьте не нажали ли на активный элемент, если так то уберите у него дополнительный класс

Рабочий пример:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activeIndex: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    changeSelect(index) {
      if (this.activeIndex === index) {
        this.activeIndex = 0
      } else {
        this.activeIndex = index
      }
    },
  },
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}

#app>div {
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

#app>div:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="i in 10" :key="i" :class="{active: i == activeIndex, green: i === 2}" @click="changeSelect(i)">
    {{ i }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: как добавлять стрелку которая будет менять своё направления взависимости от toggle click ркасного блока

Comment: мне нужно рендерить обьект а не цифры

Comment: та у меня задача такая, какой фриланс) просто в реальности будет массива а не эти цифры ...